# android loading webview in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, webview

i want to open twitter auth in my webview rather then opening in browser, any good tutorial how to play with webview in dialog and loading it inside dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just apply dialog theme to regular activity which contains a WebView.

Comment: i am having problem with that. i am using browser type of application and once i complete the Authorizing App.  It does not redirect me to my webpage.  Instead i shows me redirect but it remains on the same page.  Any idea how to deal with such problem?

Answer (score 5):

```
  Context mContext = this;
  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

  alert.setTitle("Riga");
  WebView wv = new WebView(mContext);
  String html = "<html><body>some html here</body></html>";

  wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
  alert.setView(wv);
  alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
  alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  });
  alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  });
  alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Open like dialog and register in Manifest.xml file. Use like Dialog box.**

```
public class WebDialog extends Dialog
{

    static final int                      BLUE                  = 0xFF6D84B4;
    static final float[]                  DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE =
                                                                    { 20, 60 };
    static final float[]                  DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT  =
                                                                    { 40, 60 };
    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams   FILL                    = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    static final int                      MARGIN                    = 4;
    static final int                      PADDING                   = 2;
    static final String                   DISPLAY_STRING            = "touch";

    private String                        mUrl;
//  private DialogListener                mListener;
    private ProgressDialog                mSpinner;
    private WebView                       mWebView;
    private LinearLayout                  mContent;
    private TextView                      mTitle;

    public WebDialog(Context context, String url)
    {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");

        mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        setUpTitle();
        setUpWebView();
        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int orientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        float[] dimensions = (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) ? DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE : DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT;
        addContentView(mContent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(display.getWidth() - ((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f)), display.getHeight() - ((int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f))));
    }

    private void setUpTitle()
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Drawable icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mTitle = new TextView(getContext());
        mTitle.setText("Website");
        mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        mTitle.setBackgroundColor(BLUE);
        mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
//      mTitle.setCompoundDrawablePadding(MARGIN + PADDING);
//      mTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
        mContent.addView(mTitle);
    }

    private void setUpWebView()
    {
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebDialog.DialogWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        System.out.println(" mURL = "+mUrl);

        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
        mContent.addView(mWebView);
    }

    private class DialogWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            WebDialog.this.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mSpinner.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            String title = mWebView.getTitle();
            if (title != null && title.length() > 0)
            {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }
            mSpinner.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```