# display html in popup

Tags: java, android, popup

What we do is we define a `webview` and make the `html` files being displayed in that. Is it possible to display an `html` file in android's default pop up on the same screen? I have stored the `html` file in `assets/www` folder.
Please let me know regarding this

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display a `WebView` or any other UI in a default Android `Dialog`. But, it is better and easier for you to make your own custom `Dialog` class and display the `WebView` in that. You can also make it an `Activity` and use the Dialog theme to make the `Activity` look and behave like a `Dialog`.

You are correct to put your .html file in the "assets" folder. That is what I do.

Load the `WebView` like this:

```
private final static String url = "file:///android_asset/file.html";
webview.loadUrl(baseUrl);
```