# How to make this layout (photo)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make similar layout to this one.

I achieved everything except that pop up window (saying "Perfect"). How to make this? Will pop up windows? Dialog or somehow else?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: It could be a custom dialog which appears when user finishes with the game or something which will be going on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can approach this.

If you want a view above another one you can use FramLayout. [Tutorial here.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout)

If you want it to be a dialog you can follow this tutorial [Tutorial here](http://mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example)

Answer (score 2):

The screenshoted layout look like a `WebView` to me. Thus you could try to take all advantage of the WebView to create any `html`-based layout.

The pop-up could also be a custom dialog, or just a `div` on top the main layout or whatever. For example, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup).

Comment: Does WebView requires internet? (Sorry for maybe dumb question) :D. If yes, this program works without interent.

Comment: I have an idea, maybe it is just View, that is on top? :/ and it appears by enabling, disabling it?

Comment: @whiteLT WebView requires no Internet connection to work. You could easily create your custom local HTML file, put it to the assets folder and load to the `WebView`: `loadUrl("file:///android_asset/my_super_layout.html");`