# how to open target _blank links in WebView with external browser

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I have this code, but not because it works, it keeps opening in webview and what I want is that the links do not belong to my website open in default browser. Any idea?

Can someone tell me if it's possible and how to do it? Thank you very much!

```
package com.example.webviewapp;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.JsPromptResult;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mainWebView;
    private String HomeUrl, AppName, ShareUrl, AD_ID, sdrUrl, ext;
    private VideoView mVideoView;  
    private RelativeLayout mContentView;  
    private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;  
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback; 
    private AdView adView;
    Integer vidPosition;
    ProgressBar progressBar;



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint({"CutPasteId","NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // ========================Create adView
        AD_ID = getString(R.string.admob_publisher_id);
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AD_ID);

/*      // Dynamic add LinearLayout 
        // android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayout);

        // Add adView
        layout.addView(adView);*/

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());




        //========================== home url
        HomeUrl = getString(R.string.base_url);

        //First share link
        ShareUrl = HomeUrl;

        // App name url
        AppName = getString(R.string.app_name);

        //Find objects with ID
        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        // focus with touch
        mainWebView.setFocusable(true);
        mainWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mainWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN|View.FOCUS_UP);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);

        // enabled Java Script
        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        //Customaze Web View
        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeClient()); 

        //Webview scroll
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        //Cache enable
        mainWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mainWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

        // Load Home url 
        mainWebView.loadUrl(HomeUrl);


        mainWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            String value = extras.getString("url");
            //mainWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            mainWebView.loadUrl(value);

        }

        // Menu category
        TextView text1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_bar_home);
        text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mainWebView.loadUrl(HomeUrl);
            }
        });

        // Menu category
        TextView text2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_bar_share);
        text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ShareUrl);
                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Interesting for you!");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
            }
        });
    }


    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            // On load Spinner visible
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);

         // On load Spinner hide
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //share page or link
            ShareUrl = url;

            // One touch call link <a href="tel:777777777">Call</a>
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) 
                { 
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                   Uri.parse(url)); 
                   startActivity(intent);
                }

                else

                // One touch sms link <a href="sms:1717171717">Sms</a>      
                if (url.startsWith("sms:")) 
                {
                    Intent message = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
                    startActivity(message);
                }

                    // One share text or  url link <a href="share:share text">share text</a>
                else
                    if (url.startsWith("share:")) 
                    {
                        String[] share_link = url.split(":");
                        try {
                            String ID= URLDecoder.decode(share_link[1], "UTF-8");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setType("text/plain");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+ID);
                            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Interesting for you!");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));

                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                // One touch image link <a href="test.jpg">Image</a>    
                else

                    if(url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".gif") || url.endsWith(".JPG") || url.endsWith(".jpeg") )      
                    {
                        Intent intent=new Intent (MainActivity.this, Image.class);
                        intent.putExtra("href", url);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                else
                    // else if it's a 3GP file link
                    if(url.endsWith(".3gp")){
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/3gp");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    }
                else
                    //Link mp4 file <a href="http://mosaicdesign.uz/test.mp4">Download mp4</a>
                if(url.endsWith(".mp4")){

                    if(url.startsWith("download")){
                        String[] download_link = url.split(":");

                        try {
                            //<a href="download:http://mosaicdesign.uz/test.mp4">Download mp4</a>
                            sdrUrl= URLDecoder.decode(download_link[1], "UTF-8")+":"+URLDecoder.decode(download_link[2], "UTF-8");
                            ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(sdrUrl);


                            if (ext != null) {  
                                 MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();  
                                 String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

                                 if (mimeType != null) {  
                                      if (ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp4")) {  
                                           DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) MainActivity.this  
                                                     .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);  
                                           DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(  
                                                     Uri.parse(sdrUrl));
                                           request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                                           request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
                                           request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
                                           File destinationFile = new File(  
                                                     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  
                                                     getFileName(sdrUrl, ext));  

                                           request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));  
                                           mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);  

                                      }  
                                 }  
                        }
                            return true;
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                        else
                        {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
                            startActivity(intent);
                            return true;
                        }

                    }


                    else

                //Open MP3 file <a href="http://mosaicdesign.uz/test.mp3">Download mp3</a>
                    if(url.endsWith(".mp3") || url.endsWith(".MP3")){
                        // Download files

                        if(url.startsWith("download")){
                            String[] download_link = url.split(":");

                            try {
                                //<a href="download:http://mosaicdesign.uz/test.mp3">Download mp3</a>
                                sdrUrl= URLDecoder.decode(download_link[1], "UTF-8")+":"+URLDecoder.decode(download_link[2], "UTF-8");

                                //ext=url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."));
                                ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(sdrUrl);


                                if (ext != null) {  
                                     MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();  
                                     String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

                                     if (mimeType != null) {  
                                          if (ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp3")) {  
                                               DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) MainActivity.this  
                                                         .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);  
                                               DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(  
                                                         Uri.parse(sdrUrl));
                                               request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                                               request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
                                               request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
                                               File destinationFile = new File(  
                                                         Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  
                                                         getFileName(sdrUrl, ext));  

                                               request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));  
                                               mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);  

                                          }  
                                     }  
                            }
                                return true;
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/mp3");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                        }

                    }

                //View file < a href="www.text.com/test.txt"> View text</a>
                if (   

                           url.endsWith(".pdf")
                        || url.endsWith(".txt")
                        || url.endsWith(".doc")
                        || url.endsWith(".docx")
                        || url.endsWith(".xls")
                        || url.endsWith(".xlsx")
                        || url.endsWith(".ppt")
                        || url.endsWith(".pptx")
                        || url.endsWith(".pages")
                        || url.endsWith(".ai")
                        || url.endsWith(".psd")
                        || url.endsWith(".tiff")
                        || url.endsWith(".dxf")
                        || url.endsWith(".svg")
                        || url.endsWith(".eps")
                        || url.endsWith(".ps")
                        || url.endsWith(".ttf")
                        || url.endsWith(".xps")
                        || url.endsWith(".zip")
                        || url.endsWith(".rar")

                  )
                {
                    if(url.startsWith("download")){
                        String[] download_link = url.split(":");

                        try {

                            sdrUrl= URLDecoder.decode(download_link[1], "UTF-8")+":"+URLDecoder.decode(download_link[2], "UTF-8");
                            ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(sdrUrl);


                            if (ext != null) {  
                                 MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();  
                                 String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

                                 if (mimeType != null) {  

                                           DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager) MainActivity.this  
                                                     .getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);  
                                           DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(  
                                                     Uri.parse(sdrUrl));
                                           request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                                           request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
                                           request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
                                           File destinationFile = new File(  
                                                     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  
                                                     getFileName(sdrUrl, ext));  

                                           request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));  
                                           mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);  


                                 }  
                        }
                            return true;
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=";
                    mainWebView.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);
                    return true;
                    }
                }

                else

                if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:"))     {view.loadUrl(url); }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

        }
    }

    private class MyChromeClient extends WebChromeClient  implements OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener {

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(  
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);  

        @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation,
                    WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) // Available in API level 14+, deprecated in API level 18+
            {
                onShowCustomView(view, callback);
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=14) {
                    if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {                  
                        mainWebView.addView(view, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        Gravity.CENTER));                   
                        mainWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override  
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {

              if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {  

                // mainWebView is the view that the video should've played inside.
                mainWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);  

                mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) view;  
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;  

                // mainLayout is the root layout that (ex. the layout that contains the webview)
                mContentView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RootLayout);  
                if (mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {  
                  mVideoView = (VideoView) mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild();  

                  // frame.removeView(video);  
                  mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
                  mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                  setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);  
                  mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener((OnCompletionListener) this);  
                  mVideoView.setOnErrorListener((OnErrorListener) this);  
                  mVideoView.start();  

                }  
              }  
            }  

            public void onHideCustomView() {  
              if (mVideoView == null){  
                return;  
              }else{  
              // Hide the custom view.  
              mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
              // Remove the custom view from its container.  
              mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mVideoView);  
              mVideoView = null;  
              mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
              mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();  
              // Show the content view.  
              mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
              }  
            }  

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
              mp.stop();  
              mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
              onHideCustomView();  
              setContentView(mContentView);  
            }  
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            }
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {  
              setContentView(mContentView);  
              return true;  
            }  
        //Java script alert dialog
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                    final JsResult result) {            
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                   .setTitle("Attention !")
                   .setMessage(message)
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                       new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 // do your stuff here
                                 result.confirm();
                           }
                       }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
                return true;            
            }

        //Java script confirm dialog
        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message,
                    final JsResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                   .setTitle("Confirm !")
                   .setMessage(message)
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                       new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 // do your stuff here
                                 result.confirm();
                           }
                       }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
                return true;
            }

        //Java script Prompt dialog
        @Override
        public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message,
                String defaultValue, final JsPromptResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                   .setTitle("Prompt Alert !")
                   .setMessage(message)
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                       new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 // do your stuff here
                                 result.confirm();
                           }
                       }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
                return true;
            }

    };



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_rate:
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(i);
          break;
        case R.id.action_refresh:
             mainWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );             
          break;
        case R.id.action_exit:
               finish();
              break;
        default:
          break;
        }

        return true;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {

      if(mCustomViewContainer != null){ 

      vidPosition = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
      }

      super.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {

      if(mCustomViewContainer != null){ 

      mVideoView.seekTo(vidPosition);
      }
      super.onResume();
      }
      @Override  
      public void onBackPressed() {  
            if(mCustomViewContainer != null){ 

                 mVideoView.stopPlayback();  
                 mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);  

                 if (mVideoView == null){  

                      return;  
                 }else{  

                      // Hide the custom view.  
                      mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
                      // Remove the custom view from its container.  
                      mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mVideoView);  
                      mVideoView = null;  
                      mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
                      mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();  
                      // Show the content view.  
                      mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                      setContentView(mContentView);  
                      mCustomViewContainer = null; 
                 }  
            }else if(mainWebView.canGoBack()){

                 mainWebView.goBack();

            }else{

                 super.onBackPressed(); 
            }
      }


      public String getFileName(String url, String ext1) {  
          String filenameWithoutExtension = "";  
          filenameWithoutExtension = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+ext1);

          return filenameWithoutExtension;  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in "Popup" class in Android. So it depends on what do you need from "Popup". You can use dialog as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup). Or you can create dynamically `WebView` and add it into some container (RelativeLayout for instance).

Comment: can even it open links in default browser?

Comment: @Dr.Mezo who can? `Dialog`?

Comment: iam new to android - all i need is to make this code open external links in default browser instead of browsing it inside the app

Comment: @Dr.Mezo It's your problem that you're new to Android and nobody will work for you. Specify you problem and show what you've done already to solve it and people will help you.

Comment: i know that , with the previous code i can surf my site , but when you click any external link , it view it in the same app , i want to know how to make this code open links/urls in default browser not in the same app . do you understand me ?

Answer (score 0):

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed.To open a URL/website you do the following:

```
String url = "http://www.stackexchange.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: add a button to your layout file. Add a listener to that button and in your onClick() method add the above code. That would open your default browser and navigate it to http://www.stackexchange.com