# builder (android.content.context) in builder cannot be applied to Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to load web page inside of webview.the webview load inside the Dialog.i'm tried this code.but show the error `builder (android.content.context) in builder cannot be applied to ..` and underline `this` in red line.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient();
    webview.loadUrl("http://example.com/abc.html");
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setView(webview);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Okay", null);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: try using get context

Answer (score 0):

Try This->

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setView(webView);
dialog.setPositiveButton("Okay", null);
dialog.show();
```

Check This Too-->  [android: webview inside dialog or popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup)