# Can WebView show a message dialog box with textbox?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to make an app to show an IP camera. When I use a web browser to access the camera it shows a message box in which I have to insert the username and password. I tried using the rtsp url but it doesn't show the UI to move the camera.

The message box is like this:

[image: Click]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Alert dialog or dialog box inside webview then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup) may help