# How to put android WebView in AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I'm trying to put webview in alertdialog, I'm using code I found somewhere on the stack but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Here's an example of my code:

```
holder.textView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Google:");

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.webLayout, null);

                WebView wv = view.findViewById(R.id.webview);

                wv.loadUrl(link);
                wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
                        v.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                alert.setView(view);
                alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.create().show();
            }
        });
```

webLayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

After click on button only empty dialog shows:

[image]

Comment: `for some reason, it doesn't work` you have to tell us what you mean with this. _what_ doesn't work

Comment: After click on button only empty dialog shows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android: webview inside dialog or popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172805/android-webview-inside-dialog-or-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the INTERNET Permission to the Manifest?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

You got to create an xml layout fisrt, and put the webview in the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Configure the webview as you want-->
    <WebView
        android:id="+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

create a view object instead a webview

`View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_with_webview , null)`

Now to crete a webview object use `WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview)`
Pass that view to `alert.setView(view)`

And the most important `alertDialogBuilder.show()`

Comment: show() automatically calls create(). You don't need to create yourself

Comment: Are you sure about that ?

Comment: Yes, I'd also say, that create() is not necessary.

Comment: @daniel.jbatiz updated first post, still just empty dialog shows

Comment: have you added the internet permission

Comment: wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com") works correctly on my device. So check the url you're reciving and check that webclient

Comment: to discard a problem on the webclient just try wb.loadUrl("https://www.google.com) without wv.setWebClient() code

Comment: Still nothing, It literally looks unsolvable

Comment: common, you know how to debug ok ? , so put a breakpoint at wv.loadUrl(link) and see what is inside the variable

Comment: put another at v.loadUrl(url) and check url and v

Comment: @daniel.jbatiz see picture in fisrt post

Comment: It works now with google and facebook, but it dont work with my link

Comment: whats your link ?

Comment: add to the manifest android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" inside <application>

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
alert.create().show();
```

into

```
alert.show();
```

Update:

Please use https:// in your url rather http:// or blank. Also you need to add clear text support if you really want to use non secure url. Please see how to configure here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/1084174)

Comment: It’s true that’s not necesary the create() ‘cause show() calls create() , but the error seems to be at the specific url he is trying to load (google.com is just for check if works

Comment: In that case the issues seems for the firewall. May be posters url is not permitted. He needs to check with other urls. @daniel

Comment: He tried with google and facebook and works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <application
        android:name="com.****.***"
        ****************
        ************
        *******
        .
        .
        .
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
```